# Uploading a file from Google Cloud Storage to Bigquery using Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am having trouble writing a python script that loads or exports a file from google cloud storage to google bigquery.

```
#standardSQL
import json
import argparse
import time
import uuid

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

dataset = 'dataworks-356fa'
source = 'gs://dataworks-356fa-backups/pullnupload.json'

# def load_data_from_gcs(dataset, source): 
# #     load_data_from_gcs(dataworks-356fa, 'test10', gs://dataworks-356fa-backups/pullnupload.json):
#     bigquery_client = bigquery.Client('dataworks-356fa')
#     dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(FirebaseArchive)
#     table = dataset.table(test10)
#     job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
# 
#     job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(
#         job_name, test10, 'gs://dataworks-356fa-backups/pullnupload.json')
# 
#     job.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
#     job.begin()

def load_data_from_gcs(dataset, test10, source ):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(dataset)
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('FirebaseArchive')
    table = dataset.table(test10)
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(
        job_name, table, "gs://dataworks-356fa-backups/pullnupload.json")

    job.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
    job.begin()
    job.errors
```

So far this is my code. This file will run but it does not load anything into bigquery or come back with an error message. It runs then returns me to the normal terminal view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876686/confusion-when-uploading-a-json-from-googlecloud-storage-to-bigquery), you have the `wait_for_job` function. You should use it before printing for errors, like so:

```
def load_data_from_gcs(dataset, test10, source ):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(dataset)
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('FirebaseArchive')
    table = dataset.table(test10)
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(
        job_name, table, "gs://dataworks-356fa-backups/pullnupload.json")

    job.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
    job.begin()
    wait_for_job(job)
    print("state of job is: " + job.state)
    print("errors: " + job.errors)
```

You can also use [IPython](https://ipython.org/) to run each step by hand and observe what results on each line.

Notice that `job.state` must reach 'DONE' status before looking for errors.

Comment: I added this and ran and it still does not do anything or print anything

Comment: are you calling the function `load_data_from_gcs`? Also, have you tried running these operations in iPython?

Comment: I was not calling the function thats my fault. But now when I am calling the function its saying that my table is not defined

Comment: Im going to look into IPython if I cant figure this out soon

Comment: You need to create it them. You can use either the WebUI or the python API itself for doing so. iPython will help you a lot on understanding this code.

Comment: The table is created in bigquery. This is the error message i am getting now File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 303, in api_request
    error_info=method + ' ' + url)
google.cloud.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Invalid table ID "bigquery.tables.test10". (POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/dataworks-356fa/jobs)

Comment: this is how i am calling my function. load_data_from_gcs(dataset, 'bigquery.tables.test10', source)

Comment: try just 'test10'

Comment: So now it is returning that it is running but i had to comment out wait_for_job and Print(errors) because both came back with errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148366/discussion-between-will-and-w-stephens).